# Как восстановить docker контейнер?

Tags: docker

Есть два хоста. На первом все работало, до тех пор пока не закончилось пространство. Не устанавливается ни один пакет. В общем скопировал папку на свой комп и залил на второй хост. Вопрос. Как развернуть на втором хосте этот контейнер?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Откуда скопировали, какую папку и пречем тут свободное место?

Comment: Посмотрите тут https://github.com/docker/for-win/issues/185

Answer (score -2):

docker images смотрим старый образ остался ли (будет без тега и имени).
docker ps -a смотрим что ещё осталось от ваших ранее запущенных контейнеров.
docker start параметры и имя (так и сяк) контейнера из предыдущего списка

далее спасаем все что было.
В будущем если вам нужно перманентно что-то хранить то типичных подхода 2. монтировать папку хоста в контейнер. Создавать так называемый docker volume
Вам необходимо ознакомиться с docker несколько глубже.
Хз поможет ли откопал где то